# Scheduling a daily notification with variable time for each user using cron jobs

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, cron

I have a website where each user can choose to receive a daily email reminder at the time of day he chooses (assuming same time zone for simplicity).

Hence, there is in his profile an input box with "time of day to receive email reminder".

How does one go about implementing this in a CRON job?

I thought of running something like this every minute:

```
SELECT `id`,`email` FROM `reg_users` WHERE `start_time` >= $time_now
```

the problem is that it will send more than one email.

So maybe, for each match to update a flag after sending the email.

```
UPDATE reg_users SET sent_already = 1;
```

and then the above query will be

```
SELECT `id`,`email` FROM `reg_users` WHERE `start_time` >= $time_now AND `sent_already` = 0;
```

but then would need to `UPDATE` at the end of the day all records to `sent_already = 0` with a second CRON job. seems a bit sloppy.

***Anyone have a better solution?***

Comment: Why don't you write a query that builds the `crontab` file from the table, and then let `cron` do all the scheduling?

Comment: Have a email queue with a time to send and if time to send is <= now send email. Have cron check every few min or so.

Comment: @Barmar no idea what you mean. I am using cpanel for scheduling cron jobs. so cannot access that.

Comment: why dont you let 1 process run that check every X times what/who to send ? it is not really a time/cpu conusming process and you can schedule what you want insde (like spread send during the cycle or mass send, ...)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu you mean a time interval check? problem with this is that there may be a small time discrepancy and the notification won't be in the time interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have cron run x minutes running something like.

```
SELECT `cols` FROM `Emails_Queue` WHERE `Timestamp` <= NOW() LIMIT 0,50
```

Also you should limit your query so you don't get marked as a spammer change 50 to how many you want to send at a time. I believe NOW is in [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) format.

Then you have sent the email with no errors delete the email with some sort of id (fetched from the select) so you can delete the correct email with something like.

```
DELETE FROM `Emails_Queue` WHERE `colid` = ?
```

Inserting problem. you can check with something like.

```
SELECT `cols` FROM `Emails_Queue` WHERE `User` = ? AND `Timestamp` = ?
```

Then if no returning results.

OR you could have a composite key with something like `User` AND `Timestamp` and have a `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` but this will only work if your Database Engine supports Keys. Then you can do the following.

```
INSERT INTO `Emails_Queue` (`cols`) VALUES (val)
```

OR you could have cron create them on the fly.

```
SELECT `cols` FROM `Emails_Queue` WHERE `Not_Sent` = TRUE AND `Timestamp` <= NOW() LIMIT 0,50
```

Then send emails.

```
UPDATE `Emails_Queue` SET `Not_Sent` = FALSE WHERE `User` = ?
```

and every week do the following via cron.

```
UPDATE `Emails_Queue` SET `Not_Sent` = TRUE WHERE `Not_Sent` = FALSE
```

Comment: problem is how do you prevent inserting multiple times to the mail queue? i.e. how do you initially select the records to insert only once a day?

Comment: would that need a second cron job running once a day?

Comment: You could have just 1 cron job running for sending emails. It will depend on how you want to enter the values you could have them be entered once user enters when they want to be notified or have cron run every x min for entering/checking if email isn't in queue.

Comment: Its pretty easy once you get the basics. Its just making sure the time and/or Not_Sent are correct/resetting them so you don't email people more than you need to or not sending any at all.